# Test, with pytest, that all the Flask routes have been tested

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I have a Flask App and I wrote pytest tests on all the currents routes. I want to write a test in my pytest file that will test that I tested all the routes. I already have the list of routes my app using `for route in app.app.url_map.iter_rules():` but I don't have the list of routes I have tested.
I'd like this list to be computed using either a pytest or flask functionality. A kind of `app.routes_used` property.

Comment: Activating code coverage is not enough?

Comment: Is parameterizing over app.app.url_map.iter_rules() not sufficient in your case? 

Can you elaborate more in your question?